# How to get checkbox value in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http

I want to get the value of my checkbox in Ajax so that I can save it in database as a preference for each of my user. I've never done AJAX before so i'm quite lost about it.

My javascript file :

```
$(document).ready ->
E.accounts.changeUnmarkVisibility()

$('#letters-visibility').on 'click', (e) ->
  E.accounts.changeUnmarkVisibility()

$('#label-letters-visibility').on 'click', (e) ->
  if $('#letters-visibility').is(':checked')
    $('#letters-visibility').prop('checked', false)
  else
    $('#letters-visibility').prop('checked', true)

  E.accounts.changeUnmarkVisibility()

$('#letters-visibility').on 'change', (e) ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/backend/accounts/{#id}"
        type: 'POST'
        data: 
          isChecked: $('#letters-visibility').is(':checked')
        success: (data, status, request) ->
          console.log data

  E.accounts =
    changeUnmarkVisibility: ->
      unmarkLines = $('.active-list .unmark').closest('tr')

  if unmarkLines.is(':visible')
    unmarkLines.hide()
  else
    unmarkLines.show()

)
```

My post request send me back a 404 error, I think the error is in my 'Data' option

Comment: AJAX itself wouldnt check for it being checked. You would check in jQuery and pass it through the AJAX request as a true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Deckerz is right normally you have an ajax call which has a 'Data' option and then a success option. The data is an array/object of values that you want to send.

There are lots of options on the jquery ajax page and it's quite easy to get lost in them. This though is the norm. Done is called after some.php (in this case) has finished and msg has the data that is sent back from msg. Normally you'll want this in a json format. This is good practise for if you want to send back 2 variables. e.g Status (success/error) and ErrorMessage = ""

if you're using php json_encode is the function to use to achieve this.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Comment: I understand the difference now, so I tried to insert my checkbox value in the 'Data' option and to show it on console with 'Success' option but  get a 404 error, any idea what's wrong ? ( Edit)

Comment: 404 means that the 'some.php' doesn't exist. Crack open your development tools and see which page you are hitting and amend the some.php to the right page.

Comment: I was indeed an URL error, I fixed it by passing the URL in my view, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood where you're stuck at: it seems to me you've already read the checkbox's value without problems, so I'll assume you don't know what to do with the AJAX call.

The AJAX call is really just a request to your server: you probably want to call a script (pointed to by the URL you pass), with the parameters you need to identify the user and the option, that writes the checkbox's value to the database.

One thing that may be useful to know: you don't need to construct a query string to pass your parameters along with a GET request, you can just pass them in the `data` parameter of the `jQuery.ajax` call as a regular JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX doesn't do that. AJAX returns the value. And then you look at the value to decide what to check. If you are doing this in jquery, then look here: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/